# html table image stretch cell, without nbsp

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table, stretch

[image: ques]

The only difference between these two tr is that in the right one's td, there is a nbsp before the image. Without the nbsp, the left cells are stretched like that!

What's wrong? BTW, I'm in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rowspan for right image column it will be help..

Answer (score 0):

use `rowspan` only for only cell(td) that contain image, you should try code like this

```
<td rowspan="7">YOUR_IMAGE</td>
```

replace `rowspan` amount with your number of rows.